# Cloud Functions for Firebase: Not sending notification to all users

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have created an e-commerce Android app with Firebase and a Flutter app to update the Firebase nodes.

I want to send a notification to all users whenever the admin updates the exchange rate.

Below is the code I wrote to send the update notification to all registered tokens using a Cloud Function but it only sends the notification to the Flutter app instead of both apps.

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Here is my functions code:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.helloWorld=functions.database.ref('Rates').onUpdate(evt =>{
    const payload={
        notification:{
            title:"Today's Rate",
            body :"Click here to see today's gold rate",
            badge: '1',
            sound: 'default'
        }
    }
    return admin.database().ref('fcm-token').once('value').then(allToken =>{
        if(allToken.val()){
            console.log('token available');
            const token = Object.keys(allToken.val());
            console.log(admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload));
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload);
        }else{
            console.log('No Token Available');
            throw new Error("Profile doesn't exist")
        }
    });
});
```

This is an image of my [Realtime Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMRx7.png).

Comment: There is no difference in the code for sending to a Flutter app, than for sending to an Android app. If the notification doesn't arrive, it's most likely that there's a difference in how you capture the registration token, or in how you handle the message from FCM.

Comment: `DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("fcm-token");
        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.e("Test", "FCM Registration Token: " + token);
        if(!(this.getSharedPreferences("com.jk.jkjwellers",MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("FCMAdded",false))){
            databaseReference.push().setValue(new Tokens(token));
            this.getSharedPreferences("com.jk.jkjwellers",MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("FCMAdded",true).apply();
        }`

Comment: i am registring token with this codes.
but when i m using if condition. token is not registring on firebase.and when i remove it. when user opening the app. it register it self again and again with same token

Comment: Please don't post additional information in comments, but instead edit your queston to include it.

Comment: Note- I have just tried with manual entry of token in firebase. when i put the name of node same as token and inside the node i create a new value name with token and value same as token. Then i get the notification.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMRx7.png(Image Link)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your [provided screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMRx7.png) of your database, the data below `/fcm-token` in your database has two different formats.

When you added the data manually, you used the format:

```
{
  "fcm-token": {
    "someRegistrationToken": {
      "token": "someRegistrationToken"
    },
    "someOtherRegistrationToken": {
      "token": "someOtherRegistrationToken"
    }
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Whereas, from your "auto registered" entries, you added the tokens using:

```
{
  "fcm-token": {
    "somePushId": {
      "fcmToken": "someRegistrationToken"
    },
    "someOtherPushId": {
      "fcmToken": "someOtherRegistrationToken"
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

In your Cloud Functions code, you collect all the keys stored under `/fcm-token` into an array using `Object.keys(allToken.val())` which will give you an array containing a mix of push IDs and FCM tokens which is not what you want and is why some devices are missing notifications.

So in short, decide on one format or the other.

#### Temporary work-around

With your existing mixed structure, you can use the following that will ignore what you use as the key and only extracts the token:

```js
return admin.database().ref('fcm-token').once('value').then(allTokensSnapshot => {
    if (allTokensSnapshot.exists()) {
        console.log('Tokens available');
        const tokenArray = [];
        allTokensSnapshot.forEach((tokenSnapshot) => {
            let token = tokenSnapshot.hasChild('fcmToken')
                ? tokenSnapshot.child('fcmToken').val()
                : tokenSnapshot.child('token').val();
            tokenArray.push(token);
        });

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokenArray, payload);
    } else {
        console.log('No tokens available');
        throw new Error('No tokens available');
    }
});
```

#### Database flattening

Personally, I'd flatten it out so you can use your code as-is, but this would require changing the way you add tokens to the database:

Database structure:

```js
{
  "fcm-token": {
    "someRegistrationToken": true,
    "someOtherRegistrationToken": true,
    ...
  }
}
```

(You could also use the device owner's user ID instead of `true` if desired)

Client code:

```java
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
  .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult result) {
      DatabaseReference allTokensRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("fcm-token");

      String token = result.getToken();
      Log.e("Test", "FCM Registration Token: " + token);

      SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.jk.jkjwellers", MODE_PRIVATE);
      if(!(preferences.getBoolean("FCMAdded", false))){
        allTokensRef.child(token).setValue(true);
        preferences.edit().putBoolean("FCMAdded",true).apply();
      }
    }
  })
  .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
      Log.e("Test", "Failed to get FCM registration token", e);
    }
  });
```

Comment: client code gives me nullpointerException
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jk.jkjwellers/com.jk.jkjwellers.ui.splashScreen.SplashScreenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()

Comment: @tusharkumar Client code was copied from your question. `FirebaseInstanceId#getToken()` is apparently deprecated so I have updated the answer with the modern way to get the token.

Comment: after changing the client code. i got the token in form of "SOmetoken:true"
But when i am taking value of token from node.js. it is giving me error of non-empty string. 
Because it does not have the child fcmToken or token.?
Please provide the solution trigger also. 
Sorry for the problem. But This is my first program with node.js and firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but try replacing

```
databaseReference.push().setValue(new Tokens(token));
```

with

```
databaseReference.child(token).setValue(new Tokens(token));
```